# How to export-import an odoo custom field? Some custom fields are exportable but others not

Tags: csv, odoo-8, openerp-7

I had some custom fields at sale.order model:

```
drupal_order_name = fields.Char('Drupal order name', index=True, readonly=True)
drupal_total = fields.Float('Drupal total', digits_compute= dp.get_precision('Product Price'), help="Total amount from Drupal. Compare this with the total provided by the ERP.", readonly=True)
payment_method = fields.Selection([
                    ('bank_transfer', 'Bank transference'), 
                    ('commerce_cod', 'Bank debit'),
                    ('commerce_stripe', 'Credit/Debit card'), 
                    ('pagamastarde', 'Funded payment'),
                    ('paypal_wps', 'PayPal'),
    ], string='Payment method', index=True, readonly=False)
client_notes = fields.Text('Client notes')

ship_addr_name = fields.Char('Name (shipment)')
ship_addr_phone = fields.Char('Phone number (shipment)')
ship_addr_street = fields.Char('Street (shipment)')
ship_addr_zip = fields.Char('Zip Code (shipment)', index=True)
ship_addr_city = fields.Char('City (shipment)', index=True)
ship_addr_state = fields.Char('State (shipment)', index=True)
ship_addr_country = fields.Char('Country (shipment)', index=True)
ship_addr_extra_info = fields.Char('Extra info (shipment)', index=True)
```

I can't understand why are ship_addr_* and client_notes importable (I can select them at column options to import values from CSV import wizard) and drupal_order_name, drupal_total, and payment_method are not selectable as field to match with CSV column.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any configuration I have missed?

Similar case I have exporting from (OpenERP7) sale.order state field. I can't select it to export its data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we declare field with *readonly=True* attribute then fields value are not store in database.

To avoid such problem, remove *readonly=True* attribute from your field *drupal_order_name, drupal_total, and payment_method*.

Afterwards restart Odoo server and upgrade your custom module.

Comment: Yes, I saw this detail yesterday but I couldn't post it! hehe Thank you!

Comment: I am trying to remove the readonly attribute from sale.order state field but it doesn't change after save, restart OpenERP and update the module. I go to try with a new model.

(I know is not a good practice to rewrite a base module but it was the fast way and it is the older version of our system hehe)

Comment: It should work. Or you can uninstall custom module and restart server, update module list and install it again. Keep in mind, with these trick, you will loss your data/records.

Comment: Yes, I have noted that with a module when I was migrating the code source hehe. The problem is I want to change the original sale.order. I will try with an extra module, is safer.

Comment: Is not it a little bit insecure to do editable all fields you want to import? Could be better if there was a better and more practical solution :-/

Thanks for all!

Comment: You can achieve it by adding security groups to specific fields. Or you can overriding *write()* method to write readonly fields values.

Comment: I already have changed sale.order state field to not readonly but it doesn't appear in exportable fields @Odedra. What could be happening?